# Integrate QT client in Socket.io demo

Tags: node.js, qt, sockets

I am a beginner and would like to understand how to realize this small application, using **node.js**, **socket.io** and **QT**.

I made a server-side chat, following the tutorial on socket.io/get-started/chat/.  Now I would like to create a desktop client (QT and C ++) that exploits the same server nodejs. How can I get this? [[sketch]](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24439131/node%20chat.png)

I am sorry for my bad English. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION
For this problem do not use socket.io, but normal WebSockets.

[wp for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

[QWebSockets for Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html)